# Is there a porous thin material that will cool a stream of air passed through it to an even cooler temperature on the other side?

Tags: materials

Is there a porous thin material (e.g. filter paper, membrane) that will cool a stream of air passed through it to an even cooler temperature on the other side? If this material is absorbent, could there be a chemical absorbed into the material to facilitate the cooling?

Comment: Could you improve your question? Right now I see lots of reasons for closing this question, starting from syntax, through off-topic, to unclear what you're asking :(

Comment: So sorry for this, but couldn't find anywhere else to write. Imagine a material; under it there are fans. I want cool air on top of the this material - the air will be blown by fans, and when passing through this material - which is frozen in the fridge - it will be cooled up. I hope this helps. :(

Comment: Something like the 'powder-like' material here would help too: http://www.ncbbx.en.alibaba.com/product/478226994-214138570/PCM_cooling_material.html - But couldn't find the name of this powder, too.

Comment: @trb456 yes that is a clearer version of my question. In fact that is exactly what I have been trying to ask :)